# what is in-scope namespace in relation to XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

what is exactly an in-scope namespace in relation to XPath?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the XSLT/XPath 1.0 data model the XPath 1.0 specification in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#namespace-nodes says the following about `namespace nodes`:

> Each element has an associated set of
>   namespace nodes, one for each distinct
>   namespace prefix that is in scope for
>   the element (including the xml prefix,
>   which is implicitly declared by the
>   XML Namespaces Recommendation [XML
>   Names]) and one for the default
>   namespace if one is in scope for the
>   element.

Namespace declarations and their scope are defined in the XML namespaces specification, http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#scoping says:

> The scope of a namespace declaration
>   declaring a prefix extends from the
>   beginning of the start-tag in which it
>   appears to the end of the
>   corresponding end-tag, excluding the
>   scope of any inner declarations with
>   the same NSAttName part. In the case
>   of an empty tag, the scope is the tag
>   itself.
>
> Such a namespace declaration applies
>   to all element and attribute names
>   within its scope whose prefix matches
>   that specified in the declaration.

And http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting says the following about the scope of any default namespace declaration (i.e. `xmlns="http://example.com/ns1`):

> The scope of a default namespace
>   declaration extends from the beginning
>   of the start-tag in which it appears
>   to the end of the corresponding
>   end-tag, excluding the scope of any
>   inner default namespace declarations.
>   In the case of an empty tag, the scope
>   is the tag itself.

To give you an example, with

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com/n1" xmlns:pf2="http://example.com/ns2">
  <foo>
    <bar xmlns="http://example.com/ns3">whatever</bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

the default namespace declaration `http://example.com/n1` is in scope for the `root` element and the `foo` element, but not for the `bar` element as that has its own default namespace declaration overriding the one of the outer scope. The namespace declaration `xmlns:pf2="http://example.com/ns2"` however is in scope for the root element and all its descendants.

Comment: Great answer - an answer plus a good explanation is always a good thing :)